# Valor como Object ao selecionar item no Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

O plugin Select2 funciona normalmente, o único problema é quando faço a seleção do item o valor posto no `hidden` (obrigatório para trazer dados via AJAX) fica como `[Object Value]` e não o valor especificado pela formatação.

**Segue formulário:**

```
    <form id="Teste" method="get" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="e6" name="e6" class="select2" style="width: 600px;" />

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```

**Valor no `input hidden` após a seleção:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="e6" name="e6" class="select2 select2-offscreen" style="width: 600px;" tabindex="-1" title="" value="[object Object]">
```

**JavaScript para criação do Select2:**

```
function formataResultado(item) {
    return item.Text;
}

function formataSelecao(item) {
    return item.Value;
}

$("#e6").select2({
    placeholder: "Selecionar fornecedor",
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    id: function(data){return {id: data.id};},
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:1396/Lista/_GetDropDownListFornecedor",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        quietMillis: 300,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                searchString: term,
                pageSize: 60,
                pageIndex: page,
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return {results: data.results, more: (page * 60) < data.total };
        }
    },
    formatResult: formataResultado,
    formatSelection: formataSelecao,
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
});
```

**JSON retornado pela consulta em AJAX feita pelo Select2:**

```
{"results":[{"Selected":false,"Text":"Cezar Barbara","Value":"724"},
 {"Selected":false,"Text":"Cezar Barbara","Value":"765"}],
 "total":82}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está na função `id`:

```
id: function(data){return {id: data.id};},
```

Ela não deveria retornar um objeto, e sim o próprio valor a ser atribuído ao campo escondido (que por sinal é `Value`, não `id`):

```
id: function(data){return data.Value;},
```

Provavelmente a função anterior se referia a alguma versão mais antiga do Select2 (isso explica seu `[object Object]` - pois essa é a representação padrão em string de um objeto qualquer, e como sua função `id` estava retornando um objeto...).

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pM2pH/4/) (adaptado). A propósito, fazendo dessa forma você fica livre pra mostrar um valor amigável pro usuário na sua função `formataSelecao`, não precisa exibir o `Value` na tela.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou dar uma olhada.

Quanto a paginação está correta, o controle fica no servidor.

Comment: Resolvido, eu já tinha retornado direto o valor com essa mesma ideia que você propôs, porém estava na versão antiga e dava problema. Após atualizar funcionou como esperado (3.5.++). Obrigado pela ajuda.
Remova a parte sobre paginação para um próximo usuário com dúvidas não cometa o erro de paginar errado. O dado: data.total é um campo personalizado do meu json.

Off: Entrei no seu blog e não encontrei tópico algum, você desativou ou nem começou?

Comment: @Trxplz0 Nem comecei... :P

Comment: E vai? haeuaheuaheuaheu

Comment: @Trxplz0 hahaha vamos ver... (pode notar que eu não mexo nele há tanto tempo que o certificado de segurança EXPIROU!) Eu tenho uns rascunhos começados mas não acabados, qualquer hora eu publico eles. :D